# Manipulate offsite iframe layout from main site

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a website(siteA.com) which uses an iframe from a partner(siteB.com). In the iframe there is a slider which I would like to update from my site. I can not update the sourcecode on siteB.com since it's not mine.

The use case should be as following:

1. User clicks on link ¨Houses that cost less than $100.000
2. User is sent to siteA.com/100000
3. User sees a list from siteB.com via their supplied iFrame, where the slider has been manipulated to be set on 0-100.000

Best solution would obviously be to pass on the variables in the iFrame so the receiving site could handle it, however that's not possible at the moment.

My initial thought was to manipulate it through javascript on my site, but I'm getting an error;

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match. Global Code evaluateWithScopeExtension _evaluateOn _evaluateAndWrap
```

Any ideas as to how to solve it?

Comment: you cannot. see error message.

Comment: Yes, I get the way I wanted to do it is not possible. But isn't there any other way to do it?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev He do can solve it, at least with the context he provided you should know there are a few things to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a security policy called [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

If you are partner with *siteB.com*, the solution is to request adding the following header in the response from *siteB.com*:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: siteA.com;
```

This will allow ***siteA.com*** to modify ***siteB.com*** with JavaScript trough the iFrame.

Comment: Accepting the answer since it provides information regarding why it can't be done.